# how to override a high score in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, save, nsuserdefaults

My code below calculates the reaction time for the game. The total reaction time is calculated in `totalTime`. Right now the code saves the reaction time. However the `totalTime` always equal the high score. So no high score is saved just the current score is saved. I would like the code to save the lowest `totalTime` if it's less than the current lowest `totalTime`.

```
import UIKit
class winViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet var score2: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var winningLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var foxMill: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var hhighscore: UILabel!

  public var LebelText: String?
  public var LebelText2: String?
  public var LebelText3: String?
  public var LebelText4: String?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    timeCalculation()
    loadState()
  }

  func saveScore(score: Double) {
    // Instantiate user defaults
    let userDefaults:UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    // Set your score
    userDefaults.set(score, forKey: "highScore")

    // Sync user defaults
    userDefaults.synchronize()
  }

  func loadState() {
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let score = userDefaults.double(forKey: "highScore")
    foxMill.text = "High Score: \(score)"
  }

  func timeCalculation(){
    guard let unwrapedText = self.LebelText2 else { return }
    guard let unwrapedText2 = self.LebelText else { return }
    guard let unwrapedText3 = self.LebelText3 else { return }
    guard let unwrapedText4 = self.LebelText4 else { return }

    if let myInt = Double(unwrapedText), let myInt2 = Double(unwrapedText2), let myInt3 = Double(unwrapedText3), let myInt4 = Double(unwrapedText4) {
      var totalTime = myInt + myInt2 + myInt3 + myInt4
      self.winningLabel.text = "You won"+"\n"+"Reaction time :" + String(totalTime) + " Seconds"

      guard let highScore = UserDefaults.standard.value("highScore") as? Double else { return }

      if totalTime > highScore {
        saveScore(score: totalTime)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `timeCalculation` first in your view did load which calculates your "current highscore" I suppose and you're saving that to userdefaults. But before you're saving you're not checking if it is really the high score. You need to add a condition check there.

```
guard let highScore = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "highScore") as? Double
else{return}
if totalTime>highScore{
    saveScore(score: totalTime)
}
```

Comment: in what function do I put the guard? In time calculation or saveScore?

Comment: In your `timeCalculation` just replace `saveScore(score: totalTime)` with the above code.

Comment: Also you don't need `userDefaults.synchronize()`

Comment: not working its telling me argument labels don not match any available overloads. I edited my questions with your suggestions.